# Как перемещать метку на карте, отображая местоположение пользователя?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Собственно вопрос. На карте есть ряд статических меток. Нужно показывать текущее местоположение пользователя и обновлять его раз в 1-2 секунды так, чтобы пользователь мог глядя на карту сам оценить расстояние до нужных ему меток. Своеобразный аналог навигатора.

Comment: А в чём именно сложность? Вызывайте регулярно geolocation.get(), затем myMap.panTo(). Но имейте в виду, что подобный сценарий нарушает пользовательское соглашение - требуется коммерческая лицензия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено здесь [вопрос на QnA "Как перемещать метку на карте, отображая местоположение пользователя?"](https://qna.habr.com/q/1218038?e=13214160#comment_3168584) удалением и созданием точки.

```js
var mainpoint;
{
...
if(mainpoint)
 myMap.geoObjects.remove(mainpoint);
myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoPosition);
mainpoint=myGeoPosition
...
}
```